# What is the equivalent of Objective-C category extension and method swizzling in Android?

Tags: java, android, objective-c

I am very new to Android development.

I used Objective-C category extension and method swizzling to extend existing methods. What are the equivalent strategies in Android development?

An example is a category of ViewController and swizzling the viewDidLoad method:

```
@implementation ViewController (Swizzle)

+ (void) load {

Method original, swizzled;

original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewDidLoad));

swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzle_viewDidLoad));

method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);  

}

- (void) swizzle_viewDidLoad {

//Do my stuff here and then call the original viewDidLoad method 

[self swizzle_viewDidLoad];

}

@end
```

Comment: For the benefit of us poor Java developers who have not had the benefit of being taught Objective-C jargon, can you include a brief explanation of the terms _category extension_ and _swizzled_? It may be something like subclassing, overriding methods, and calling `super.whatever()`, but that's only guessing.

Comment: I don't think Java has the category feature.

Comment: Last I heard, java had neither method swizzling or category extensions.  For the benefit of the uninitiated, swizzling is allows you to change the implementation of specific methods at run time, usually on system level objects.  Category's allow you to extend the functionality of any class (not subclassing) by adding methods and/or properties at compile time.

Comment: Note that categories are not analogous to subclassing as they allow you to extend the functionality of existing classes.  For instance, it would allow you to add methods to java.string, that all java.string objects would then inherit.

Comment: @David - Thanks. So perhaps category extensions are roughly like C#'s partial classes?

Comment: @TedHopp roughly yes.  IIRC, C# partial classes must still be set up  with the original class, ie., you couldn't use partial classes to add methods to the base string class.

Comment: a ObjC Category is a runtime patch (monkeypatch). A Swizzle is a type of ObjC Category that replaces the functionality of an existing class method.

Comment: I wouldn't categorize it as such Bahl, although swizzling absolutely qualifies.

Comment: Just a note that you should probably run the method swizzling within a dispatch_once block since you are modifying global state.